# Python Selenium find all records

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to get all the records with `find_elements`

Here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv
import sys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://au.finance.yahoo.com/')
time.sleep(5)

search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'yfin-usr-qry')
search_box.send_keys('TSLA')
time.sleep(5)
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)


historical_data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="quote-nav"]/ul/li[4]/a/span')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click(on_element = historical_data)
action.perform()
time.sleep(5)

Table  = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-HistoricalDataTable-Proxy"]/section/div[2]')
TableList=[]
for value in Table:
    TableList.append(value.text)
    print(value.text)
```

However, it only got me the records till 02 May 2023, not all the way down to 23 Sept 2022.

Could anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151054/scroll-down-google-maps/77152152#77152152).

Actually, your table is not fully rendered after entering Historical data, it renders only when you scroll below last rendered `tr`.

So, to get table fully loaded via Selenium, you should first scroll to the last `tr` via `ActionChains` and then scroll a bit down (simulating user actions) and then check if new rows appeared.

In the code below I shortened your table locator to `[data-test=historical-prices] tbody tr`

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
# your imports

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

def continuous_scroll_with_result(by, locator):
    result = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by, locator)))
    while True:
        temp = result[-1]

        action_chains.scroll_to_element(temp).perform()
        for i in range(3):
            action_chains.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
            time.sleep(0.5)
        wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(temp)
        result = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by, locator)))
        if result[-1] == temp:
            break
    return result

# your code until Historical data is opened

Table = continuous_scroll_with_result(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-test=historical-prices] tbody tr')
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, @Yaroslavm