# Why is my code not scrolling the page to the bottom of YouTube?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dom

Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
# create webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# navigate to page
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/@freecodecamp/videos')

# scroll down to the bottom of the page
while True:
    # scroll down 1000 pixels
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 1000)')

    # wait for page to load
    time.sleep(2)

    # check if at bottom of page
    if driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset \>= document.body.offsetHeight'):
        break

driver.quit()
```

I tried using the conditional to break out of the scrolling loop when reaching the bottom of the page. Even tried referencing heights of the webpage for it.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites block native JS scroll, so executing this function doesn't work in every case.

To scroll down you should implement continuous scroll - scroll to the last video thumbnail item and to scroll a bit down via keyboard to make next items being rendered.

Solution is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151054/scroll-down-google-maps/77152152#77152152)

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

def continuous_scroll_with_elements(by, locator):
    while True:
        results = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by, locator)))
        temp = results[-1]
        actionChains.scroll_to_element(results[-1]).perform()
        for i in range(3):
            actionChains.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
            time.sleep(0.5)
        wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(temp)
    
        results = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by, locator)))
        if results[-1] == temp:
            break

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/@freecodecamp/videos")

continuous_scroll_with_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ytd-rich-grid-media[class]')
```

Comment: its giving StaleElementReferenceException  error after running this code

Comment: @AbhayLakra are you sure that you're running only my code without yours? In my code (first, it works ok for me) StaleElementReferenceException can't happen, as far as all scrolled elements on the page are present after render. They aren't disappear on scroll, so, they are exist and reference for them is stale. I think, that after scroll you did smth else, like click on video and go back to the previous screen, etc.