# Difficulty making selenium scroll down and up

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to crawl a website but the page has infinite loading. However, if I scroll all the way down, the rest of the page won't load and I realized the browser behavior is that I have to scroll up again and wait. However with several experiments I could not make selenium scroll back up again, could someone help fix the code so that it scrolls back up and load the page?

Also in this case, should I use chrome option eager mode or not? The code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
import random
import requests, time, random, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element
from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert

# from chromedriver_path import *


def save_pagesources(url):

#     API_KEY = ''
#     headers = {
#     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',}

# payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(0.5)

    # driver.maximize_window()

    # click button

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="Button Modal-closeButton Button--plain"]').click()

    scrolls = 100
    while True:
        scrolls -= 1
        # driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 6000)")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4000);")

        time.sleep(5)

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")

        # Try to find the button element
        try:
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="Card"]/a/button[contains(text(), "写回答")]')
                                                  )
            )
            # If the button is found, break out of the loop
            break
        except:
            pass

        if scrolls < 0:
            break

    html = driver.page_source

    return(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def chromedriver_path():
        chromedriver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
        return(chromedriver_path)


    chromedriver_path = chromedriver_path()
    chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.page_load_strategy='eager'
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')


    # proxy_options = {
    #     'proxy': {
    #         'http': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',        'https': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
    #         'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    #     }
    # }

    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)


    # test
    # url_list_sample = url_list[0]

    url_list = ['https://www.zhihu.com/question/48067420']

    for i in tqdm(range(0,len(url_list))):
        random_list = [9,2,5,4,8]
        sleep_time = random.sample(random_list,1)[0]
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        html = save_pagesources(url_list[i])
        filename = 'zhihu_html/zhihu_'+str(i)+'.html'
        print(filename)
        with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(html)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Does this approach works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200637/why-is-my-code-not-scrolling-the-page-to-the-bottom-of-youtube/77201704#77201704

Comment: @Yaroslavm I'm trying to find a way to scroll down without referring to a specific element – 
As

Comment: Have you tried to use `action_chains.scroll_by_amount(0, -1000).perform()`?