# Scroll up in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I want to automatically scroll up the results on google maps as shown in the picture. Through this, i can get more results to scrap. Right now, only 6 are being shown and upon moving up, more results come into the screen.

[image]

.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77152152/20292589

Comment: Found the solution. Thank you!